# Android app connectivity to remote database in Derby

Tags: java, android, sql, database-connection, derby

I am trying to connect an android app to a derby database on a pc to get data form that. For this i googled a database specially for this purpose i.e. [Awake SQL](http://www.awake-sql.org). I tried the following code for the connection to the derby database. The code is of a function which is called on the button click of the android app.

```
public void getData(View view)
{
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527"; 

            String username = "user"; 
            char [] password = {'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '1'};


            try
            {
            Connection connection  
            = new AwakeConnection(url, username, password); 

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

Actually this code was given in the user guide of Awake SQL.
When i run the above code i get the debugging mode of the eclipse. I cant get any error in the console. I am not sure if i am doing it right or not. I am still unable to connect the database for the android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see Derby listed as a supported database at http://www.awake-sql.org/

Comment: could there be any other option on that? Will shifting my database to mysql solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

//Pre-driver

```
static {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver());
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review]()